# acumatica report designer union tables

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way in Acumatica report designer to union two tables? I find that you have to link table to use them in reports.  For example can you get data based on a date range from AP Invoice and AR Invoice without having a third table to link them together?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DAC created over a SQL VIEW with UNION ALL and added to ReportDesigner is likely the best approach, but perhaps a FULL JOIN will work for your purpose.

This link describes Full Join or Union All: 
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm

For your example in ReportDesigner, APInvoice could be FULL JOIN to ARInvoice on FinPeriod and Vendor/Customer on relationships tab, offer From/To date range parameters on parameters tab with defaults such as @monthStart and @monthEnd. Conditions tab could limit results to WHERE DocBal NotEqual 0. Display textboxes could use an IsNull such as:

=IsNull([APInvoice.DocBal],[ARInvoice.DocBal])